# What is the relation between the Camera and the Canvas in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I'm not understanding the relationship between these two objects. I'm searching for a good explanation but I can't find anything simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to define in a simple way what is Canvas and Camera.

The Canvas is the area that all UI elements (buttons, panels, text...) should be inside.(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html)

A Camera is a device through which the player views the world (player, enemies, props, buttons...).
(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html)

Everything the camera sees is the **screen space** or **world space**. The canvas is overlapped on the Camera. So the relation between them are Render modes of Canvas, they allow you to represent the user interface in different ways (**screen space - overlay**, **screen space - camera** or **world space**).

I hope it's helpful.
Regards!

Comment: Minor note: if a Canvas ever asks for an "event camera" set it! If unset, the engine calls `Camera.main` to get the main camera, and `Camera.main` is an *uncached `GameObject.Find` call* which is **slow.**

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE It's not a `GameObject.Find` call, it's a `FindGameObjectsWithTag` call because it's searching for the object with the 'MainCamera' tag.